# compare lists and retain duplicates

Tags: text-processing, join

I have one lists with many duplicates, for example:

```
AARC
AARC
AARC
TNGT
TNGT
TNGT
CAAC
CAAC
```

And one list without any duplicates, for example:

```
AARC
TNGT
YUGT
BATR
```

etc.

All of the entries in the first list will appear in the second list, but not vice versa.

I want to compare the lists and find out how many entries are in both, however I want to retain and recognize duplicates. For example, the output could either be:

```
AARC
AARC
AARC
TNGT
TNGT
TNGT
```

Or

```
AARC\tAARC
AARC\tAARC
AARC\tAARC
TNGT\tTNGT
TNGT\tTNGT
TNGT\tTNGT
```

The issue I'm having is that comm grabs the first duplicate and moves on, counting subsequent entries as not being shared. Every article I can find online references removing duplicates, not retaining them. There used to be a database I could use for this, but they recently changed their default behavior to removing duplicates, and with thousands of entries I can't do it by hand :/

Comment: You say “All of the entries in the first list will appear in the second list”, but if that were true, the answer would be ``cat file1``.  The question becomes non-trivial because `CAAC` is in the first list but not in the second list.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand that well, you want to filter out all the words from first list that are not in the second list.

You can use [`grep`](http://www.skrenta.com/rt/man/grep.1.html) for that. This command:

```
grep -w -f list2.txt list1.txt
```

Will output:

```
AARC
AARC
AARC
TNGT
TNGT
TNGT
```

Check also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332732/using-grep-to-filter-out-words-from-a-stopwords-file).